# Convert WKT Polygon to ESRI Geometry String in Standalone Python Script

Tags: python, geometry, software-recommendations, well-known-text

I am trying to convert a WKT String like this to ESRI Geometry String. I am looking for a solution that does not require an ArcGIS license.

> Polygon ((-95.92442111883893574 30.18765532529553752,
> -95.80900212955509687 30.02964123282361086, -95.79388773810126168 30.11620547478649002, -95.88045198006413727 30.25360903345773167, -95.92442111883893574 30.18765532529553752))

An ESRI Geometry String looks something like this. (Not the same Polygon)

> {   "rings" :
> [[[-97.06138,32.837],[-97.06133,32.836],[-97.06124,32.834],[-97.06127,32.832],
> [-97.06138,32.837]],[[-97.06326,32.759],[-97.06298,32.755],[-97.06153,32.749],
> [-97.06326,32.759]]] }

Comment: If you don't have an ArcGIS license why do you want to end up with an Esri geometry string?

Comment: I want to query an ArcGIS Feature Layer like this one. One of the parameters is ESRI Geometry for a Polygon to get only features intersecting. https://services.twdb.texas.gov/arcgis/rest/services/Base/BaseLayerQueryService/MapServer/8/query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my best guess using shapely.  I haven't looked into the spec, just going off of your example:

```
import json
import shapely.wkt

wkt = 'Polygon ((-95.92442111883893574 30.18765532529553752, -95.80900212955509687 30.02964123282361086, -95.79388773810126168 30.11620547478649002, -95.88045198006413727 30.25360903345773167, -95.92442111883893574 30.18765532529553752))'

geom = shapely.wkt.loads(wkt)

rings = [list(geom.exterior.coords)] + \
        [list(interior.coords) for interior in geom.interiors]

esri = json.dumps({'rings': rings})

print(esri)
```

Gives:

```
{"rings": [[[-95.92442111883894, 30.187655325295538], [-95.8090021295551, 30.02964123282361], [-95.79388773810126, 30.11620547478649], [-95.88045198006414, 30.25360903345773], [-95.92442111883894, 30.187655325295538]]]}
```

Comment: That's awesome. I wasn't thinking about custom function, but this is doing exactly what I needed. Do you know if it will deal with Multi Polygon and Polygon etc? I will check myself as well and then will accept the answer.

Comment: I'm not sure, it will probably choke on multipolygons but wouldn't be difficult to modify if you have examples of the format

Answer (score 1):

You could check the wkt-type for MultiPolygons. Extending mikewatt's code sample it could look like the following (sorry I do not have enough reputation to comment):

```python
    import json
    import shapely.wkt
    
    geom = shapely.wkt.loads(wktpoly)
    
    rings = None
    # test for polygon type
    if geom.geom_type == 'MultiPolygon':
        rings = []
        for pg in geom.geoms:
            rings += [list(pg.exterior.coords)] + [list(interior.coords) for interior in pg.interiors]    
    elif geom.geom_type == 'Polygon':
        rings = [list(geom.exterior.coords)] + [list(interior.coords) for interior in geom.interiors]
    else:
        print("Shape is not a polygon")
        return None
            
    # convert to esrigeometry json    
    esri = json.dumps({'rings': rings})
```